# cl.exe mismatch between compiler and library versions when building Universal app

Tags: c++, windows, win-universal-app, windows-10-universal

I'm trying to build a Windows Universal app using cl.exe from the command line. I've pasted in the command line parameters from one of the Visual Studio templates, but I still can't get it working.  I get the following error:

```
F:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\INCLUDE\vccorlib.h(348): error C3940: 'EventRegistrationToken': identifier not found - possible mismatch between compiler and library versions. Please ensure vccorlib.h/.lib, vccorlib120.dll and c1xx.dll match
```

It appears that it is using the wrong include libraries.

The cl.exe command line also includes the following options for include files:

```
/LIBPATH:"F:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\\lib\store\amd64"
/LIBPATH:"F:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\\lib\amd64"
```

Answer (score -3, accepted):

Fixed this by running vcvarsall.bat with the appropriate option, beforehand.

Comment: Could you please elaborate? I have the same exact error and I ran vcvarsall.bat amd64 10.0.xxxx.0 to match my new sdk version but that didn't fix it. If you still remember what was the issue, I appreciate a response.

Comment: more info needed!